# Div overlay canvas, mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, hover

[image: canvas area with divs]

I have canvas area, where i can add some images.
And i want to cut whole canvas to parts and download just one part of image.

If i put divs with color overlay canvas, i can't move my elements inside.
But i want to show users which area has been selected and will be downloaded.

Is it possible to show some divs overlay canvas and also manage with canvas?

If don't how can i listening mouseover event for my div which is invisible, because have lower z-index, than my canvas image ?

Comment: I've posted an answer showing how to use an overlay canvas to "tint" the currently selected portion of your image. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to color your divs, you use a second (overlay) canvas on top of your image canvas to tint the desired parts of your image canvas underneath.

- Define a javascript object representing each part (rectangle) of your canvas.
- Place a second overlay canvas over your image canvas and tell it not emit events using CSS: `pointer-events:none`.
- On mousemove, fill the part of the overlay canvas under the mouse with semi-transparent color.

[image][image]

**Here is example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var overlay=document.getElementById("overlay");
var octx=overlay.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }



var selectedPart=1;
var parts=[];

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/sailboatSmall.png';
function start(){

  cw=canvas.width=overlay.width=img.width;
  ch=canvas.height=overlay.height=img.height;

  octx.font='18px verdana';
  octx.textAlign='center';
  octx.textBaseline='middle';
  octx.lineWidth=0.50;
  octx.fillStyle='red';
  octx.globalAlpha=0.10;

  parts.push({x:0,y:0,w:cw/3,h:ch/2});
  parts.push({x:cw/3,y:0,w:cw/3,h:ch/2});
  parts.push({x:cw*2/3,y:0,w:cw/3,h:ch/2});
  parts.push({x:0,y:ch/2,w:cw/2,h:ch/2});
  parts.push({x:cw/2,y:ch/2,w:cw/2,h:ch/2});

  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

  $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  var x=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  var y=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  for(var i=0;i<parts.length;i++){
    var p=parts[i];
    if(x>p.x && x<p.x+p.w && y>p.y && y<p.y+p.h){
      if(i==selectedPart){return;}
      selectedPart=i;
      octx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
      octx.fillRect(p.x,p.y,p.w,p.h);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
#container{position:relative;}
#canvas,#overlay{position:absolute;}
#overlay{pointer-events:none;border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Move mouse over image parts</h4>
<div id=container>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
  <canvas id="overlay" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: than div is invisible.
I want to set color with opacity.
Is it possible ?

Comment: I'm sorry. 
With pointer-events: none 
i can't detect event onmouseevent.

Comment: @iiylll Pardon. I think I misunderstood your question -- I thought you wanted to have the canvas respond to events while having div's on top of the canvas.. Could you explain what you need?

Comment: I have ruler like in photoshop.
And i can cut whole canvas to small pieces with it and download separetly each of them by click on the particular part of canvas.

I want to fill my canvas with color + opacity in that part, where mouse is.